# Spring boot change override exception responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to customize exception responses and use my own response structure, I am using below way :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
...
    }
}
```

But I have not accessed to the status code, I need status code that defined in exceptions via `ResponseStatus`:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
public class ExtendSubscriptionReminderNotExistException extends RuntimeException
{
}
```

Comment: Do you need to retrieve code from the exception's annotation and set it to response code in your `GlobalExceptionHandler#handle `?

Comment: If I could override ResponseStatusExceptionResolver ,doResolveException is the method that I want

Answer (score 1):

With java reflection mechanism, you can do it like so:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (ex instanceOf ExtendSubscriptionReminderNotExistException) {
            ResponseStatus status = ExtendSubscriptionReminderNotExistException.class.getAnnotation(ResponseStatus.class);
            return ResponseEntity.status(status.value()).body(ex.getMessage());
        }else{
            //if it's not ExtendSubscriptionReminderNotExistException, do sth different
        }
    }
```

Here is an useful article on how to read annotation in java: [Java Reflection - Annotations](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html)

If you want to override ResponseStatusExceptionResolver, then you should `extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` and implement your own `doResolveException` like [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/313a7836b091d20dbb9763b3677d559fea32d13d/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.java) did, then create a configuration extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and override [configureHandlerExceptionResolvers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cd6085a31009e830b63461b71ae69e39afeac27c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L1003), then spring will **pick up your own exception resolver over the default one**. The logic behind this is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cd6085a31009e830b63461b71ae69e39afeac27c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L985).

Comment: If I could override ResponseStatusExceptionResolver ,I think doResolveException is the method that I want

Comment: you can definitely override ResponseStatusExceptionResolver, see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong on this one, but to me it doesn't really make sense to use *@ResponseStatus* annotation and a custom *ErrorHandler* at the same time.
Annotations are supposed to make your code easier to understand and to avoid using such handlers.

If you really want to use the handler, I'd suggest to drop the annotation and store the corresponding status code in each exception (as a `final static` attribute for example).

Answer (score 0):

we cannot change exception messages. However determine we can change the code and class, and throw a new one by overriding the same class with the same code and different message.

Comment: you can do this by using  try-catch for example
try{
    functioncall();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new MyException('new message');
}

Comment: If I could override ResponseStatusExceptionResolver ,doResolveException is the method that I want